# Copy & Paste Selection Based On Combo Box Selection

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I hope someone can help with this?

I want to copy selected data from another sheet based on a combo box selection. What needs to happen is :-

If the selection in the combo box is "Access Pricing" then I want Price data from second sheet to populate in the price column in my first sheet. There is already a default price data in the first sheet which needs to be deleted first.

Below is the code I tried but its not working.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

 If ComboBox2.Value = "Access Pricing" Then
 Sheets("IV Fluids Pricing Grid").Range("k19:k27").Copy Sheets("Pricing Tier").Range("C6:C14")

 End If

End Sub
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction for a relatively easy way to do this it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Abhishek

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for you to simply write a smart formula based on the cell link of the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you work with the cell link and change your formula. Else you can try this
Assuming that the combobox named `Dropdown 1` is in the sheet named `My Sheet`

```
with sheets("My Sheet").shapes("Dropdown 1").ControlFormat

If .list(.value) = "Access Pricing" Then
  Sheets("IV Fluids Pricing Grid").Range("k19:k27").Copy Sheets("Pricing Tier").Range("C6:C14")
End If

end with
```

[This](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/5/14/vba-for-excels-form-control-combo-boxes) is a good link for form control in VBA

Comment: Thank you Raunak.
How do I copy paste values and not the formula?